# How to override constraint programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

Initially I set the height of my container as 75. But on `viewWillLoad` I want to update this value and set to `width / 5`.

For this I try:

```
containerHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: container, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: width / 5)
container.addConstraint(containerHeight)
```

Also:

```
    containerHeight.constant = width / 5
```

but both variants doesn't update my constraint. It stills returns me 75. What's wrong?

Comment: You need to call [UIView layoutIfNeeded] after updating the constant

Comment: he updates those in viewWillLoad does he still have to call layoutIfNeeded?

Comment: @hasan83 how need I use it?

Comment: You have to do it in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: @Arbitur no, it doesn't help me. I tried it

Comment: do you have an outlet for your storyboard constraint? do not add a new one programmatically. just update the existing one. is that what r u doing?

Comment: Why are you adding a new one? That would just ruin the existing one or not work at all.

Comment: @hasan83 yes, I try `containerHeight.constant = 50`. Is it right?

Comment: @Arbitur no, I use just one. I just tried both variants =/

Comment: do you have an outlet for your storyboard constraint?

Comment: do you have an outlet for your storyboard constraint?

Comment: Use your second approach of altering the `.constant` property. After this call `setNeedsLayout` on your `container`.

Comment: @Gandalf doesn't work :/

Comment: Why are you adding this constraint programmatically? It's possible in a storyboard to constrain the width of an element to a fraction of it's height. ctrl + click and drag from the view to itself and select 'aspect ratio'.

Answer (score 5):

If you already have an existing constraint created in storyboard you can just add an `IBOutlet` and change its constant, dont make a new one...

And put your code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    constraint.constant = 10 // Just to test and see it really works 75 -> 10

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded() // If iOS 7

    // I think constraints are updated after this function and you wont see a change in the frame.height until it has ran. Put your print in an async and you'll see the updated frame.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        print(view.frame.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work =/ When I print `print(container.frame.height)` it returns 75 =/

Comment: @Orkhan Where do you print?

Comment: under `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: I think you have to check the height later than that, out of scope, put it into an dispatch_async, Ill update

Comment: This is odd... What kind of view is it? What is its Content Compression Resistance Priority? What is the constraints priority?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92240/discussion-between-orkhan-and-arbitur).

Answer (score 0):

Two thing. either you are testing on a device or simulator with 4.7 inch screen. which its width/5 = 375/5.0 = 75.

Or, in the viewWillLoad the width you are getting is the storyboard view width not the actual device view width.

try to change the place of that to viewWillAppear and call layoutIfNeeded. or try to get screen width rather than the view frame.

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
```

use the following method:

```
containerHeight.constant = width / 5
```

The other one is wrong.

Comment: How to call layoutIfNeeded? No, I print this value and it 64, not 75

Comment: try the other suggestion. and you can call it as [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

Comment: it still doesn't update my container height.  `print(container.frame.height)` still returns 75

Comment: it returns me in logs: `
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe888f260a0 V:[UIView:0x7fe888f24540]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fe888f24eb0]>", 
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe888f262d0 V:[UIView:0x7fe888f24540]-(75)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fe888f256a0]>", 
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe888f26370 V:[UIView:0x7fe888f24eb0]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fe888f256a0]>", 
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe888df0810 V:[UIView:0x7fe888f24eb0(64)]>"`

Answer (score 0):

You should change constrain constant in viewDidLayoutSubviews instead of viewWillLoad - viewWillLoad means that view isn't loaded already, so constrains isn't also

Comment: viewDidLoad - called once per view controller _after_ the view has been loaded.